# How to count a certain character/ replaced character

Tags: c++

```
...
v.push_back(s);
}

for (int i =0; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
int a_pos = -1;
a_pos = v[i].find('a');
if (a_pos != -1)
v[i][a_pos] = '@';

}

cout<< v.size() << " ";
```

Edited to remove my previous whole code, as only this part was/is needed in order to answer my question. Rest of code solved the issue, while this part 'counted' the appropriate character.

Comment: Welcome! I would advise you to look toward the standard library algorithms.

Comment: Do you need a count of the words with replaced *a*?

Comment: Yes, I know that my v.size needs to be replaced but I cannot figure out with what, I've tried other inputs from the code, and even else if statements to try and get through but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it to output the count of the replacements then the most direct way is to just introduce a dedicated `counter` variable and increment it at every replacement:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    string s; 
    int numOfStrings;
    cin>>numOfStrings;
    unsigned counter = 0; // Our counter

    for (int i =0; i < numOfStrings; ++i) {
        cin>>s;
        v.push_back(s);
    }

    for (int i =0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        int a_pos = -1;
        a_pos = v[i].find('a');
        if (a_pos != -1) {
            v[i][a_pos] = '@';
            ++counter; // Done a replacement, increment the counter
        }
    }

    cout << "Counter: " << counter << endl; // Print the count of replacements

    for (auto elem : v) { // Print all the elements in our vector of strings
        cout<< elem <<" ";}
```

Example:

```
Input: 
2 bar foo
    
Output: 
Counter: 1
b@r foo
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I attempted to do it through this manner using count++ but could not get it to work

Comment: @user16101600 then I hope you'll benefit from considering what is different among your `counter` version and this one. Don't forget to accept the answer if it is what you was looking for.